# Xamarin.Forms Android content files

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get Tess-Two (Tesseract OCR fork for Android) working using Xamarin.Forms but for my OCREngine to initialize, I need the path to the folder containing the language data. I've put this data into a folder and marked it as 'Content' with the 'Copy Always' option.

For some reason I can't seem to reference (or even find) the files I've marked as content.

Simply put: I need a folder with some files that need to be copied onto the device and I need to be able to get the path to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android, you want to include the files as [Assets](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_6_-_using_android_assets/).

Android provides an AssetManager class that allows you to open and read Assets

```
string content;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (Assets.Open ("read_asset.txt")))
{
    content = sr.ReadToEnd ();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. How would I go about getting a path to a folder with this? What the OCREngine needs is a string path, it then checks the directory you provide to see if it contains a 'tessdata' directory and that this folder contains the right files. Do you understand the problem here?

Comment: Asset files are embedded in your app bundle - I don't think you can directly reference their path.  if your lib will ONLY work with a file path, you can open them as a stream and then write them to SpecialFolders.Personal and then pass that path to your lib.

Comment: Thank you, I thought there was a way to do it without having to write them to the internal memory. Thanks again.